# How to set the effective time series storage time in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask, how to set the time of effective data storage in Apache IoTDB? What function should I use and how should I write the setting SQL statement to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ttl` function in Apache IoTDB, for example, `set ttl to root.db 360000`. This can let you retain only the data within a certain time range from writing.